# Dojo - dijit multiple column in the combo box

Tags: dojo, multiple-columns

How can I write a dijit autocomplete combo box that contains multiple columns, such as this...

1. john, doe, cod 13, street sample 1
2. steve, smith, cod 14, street sample 2
3. micheal, james, cod 14, street sample 3

This is my code:

```
var filteringSelect = new dijit.form.ComboBox({
    id: "managerSelect",
    name: "managers",
    value: "",
    store: managerStore,
    searchAttr: "serial"
    },
"managerSelect");
}
```

However it only shows a single column like this:

1. john
2. steve
3. micheal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly,you need to override "labelFunc" for combo box. E.g.

// define combo box

```
var filteringSelect = new dijit.form.ComboBox({
                    id: "managerSelect",
                    name: "managers",
                    value: "",
                    store: managerStore,
                    searchAttr: "serial",
                    labelFunc:"myLabelFunc"
                    },
                    "managerSelect");
                }
```

// define labelFunc

```
function myLabelFunc(item, store){
            var label=store.getValue(item, 'first')+","+store.getValue(item, 'last');
            return label;
        }
```

[HTML page - Example](http://pastehtml.com/view/1dt134z.html)